# how to selenium crawling text in iframe

Tags: python

I want to crawl and display this text with Selenium

[dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmoby.png)

I want to crawl and display this text with Selenium

There is an element inside the Iframe, so I need to enter the Iframe and crawl it. How can I enter it?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/